# Change wx.Frame size inside class

Tags: wxpython

I have created a `wx.frame class` with `wxpython`.
I'd like to change the `frame's` size inside the class, is it possible?
i know set the `frame's` size when `init`, like

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame,self).__init__(None, -1, title="demo", size=(width, height))
    def change_frame_size(self)
```

I'd like to create a function inside the class, which can change the frame's size to maximum. anybody knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SetSize`](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetSize) method can be used to change the size of a window.

```
def change_frame_size(self, width, height):
    self.SetSize(wx.Size(width, height))
```

In order to maximize a window, you have `Maximize` method.

```
self.Maximize()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SetSize()`
e.g.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, title="Window", pos = (100,150), size =(250,200))
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(1,'&Resize Max')
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(2,'Resize &Min')
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(3,'E&xit')
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menu,'&File')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMax, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMin, id=2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=3)
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.SetMaxSize((500,400))
        self.SetMinSize((250,200))
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()

    def OnMax(self, evt):
        self.SetSize(self.MaxSize)
        print("MyFrame resized bigger!")

    def OnMin(self, evt):
        self.SetSize(self.MinSize)
        print("MyFrame resized smaller!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```